# Round off to a next number with two decimal places

Tags: php

Need help:

What I want is the number `1099.924343` to become `1100.00`

When I do this:

```
$number=1099.924343;
echo ceil($number); 
echo "<br>";
echo round($number,2);
```

This is the result I get:

```
1100
1099.92
```

Please give some suggestion.

Comment: Append a `00` with `ceil()` ? `echo ceil($number).'00';`

Comment: A simple solution, worked! I dnt knw why i dint think of this!, thnx

Comment: How about `number_format(round($number),2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do

```
echo  number_format( ceil( $number ), 2 );
```

Read more:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: For a string that will *always* be `.00` there's absolutely no reason to use `number_format`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo There is if they are prices and you want your output to look neat and tidy.

Comment: @DarrenCook There's no reason to use a function to do something as simple as string concatination. This will **never** output anything different than `ceil($number) . '.00'`. It'd be like having to output `2 + 3 = 5` and you'd do `'2 + 3 = ' . (2 + 3)`. I realize my original comment might've been ambiguous about that (I never meant `.00` wasn't needed - I meant it was an unnecessary call to a function).

Answer (score 0):

Bad news. `1100` ***already is*** `1100.00`. If you want to display a number with additional decimal places than it has, that's a *display* problem.

```
printf('%.2f', 1100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just using:

```
round($number)
```